# Run a computed function through a button, altering a CSS class, through a v-bind directive

Tags: javascript, css, vuejs2

I am trying to run a function that alters the `width` of a `<div>` randomly triggering the function through a button, using `vuejs`

When I first tested the function, instead of using `:style="width"` I was using `:style="lifeBar"` on my `<div>` and every time I ran the code the bar would have it's width changed randomly. In other words, the function is working well.

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <div :style="width" 
  class="healthbar text-center" 
  style="background-color: green; 
  margin: 0; color: white; width: 100%">
  </div>
//I just could not figure out what to do below to make the function run on the div above
<button @click="lifeBar">testing random</button>
</div>
```

JS

```
new Vue({
el: "#app",
data: {
     width: 100
},
computed: {
     lifeBar: function() {
     var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*100)
     return {width: rand + '%'}
     }
}
})
```

What I want to figure out is how do I trigger this function to modify the `width` every time I hit the `button`

Thanks to all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to call a method on click which updates a data value which your computed then uses to return the CSS. That would look something like this:

```html
<div :style="lifeBar">
    [...]
</div>
<button @click="setWidth">testing random</button>
```

```js
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        width: 100
    },
    methods: {
        setWidth() {
            this.width = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        }
    },
    computed: {
        lifeBar() {
            return {
                width: `${this.width}%`;
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you @Daniel Samuels! This was very enlightening